# realm apply where clause to the innerRealm list

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I have a realm object mySchool which contains a realm list of class myClass which contains a realmlist of myStudents.

```
    myschool{
             realmsList<myClass>{
                                 realmList<myStudests>{
                                                       bool isPresent
                                                      }
                                 }
             }
```

something like this.

now I need to fetch the schools with a list of classes with present students.

I need to filter out the students who are not present. and the class with no students.

I tried `where("myClass.myStudent.ispresent",true)` but it dosen't work.

is it possible to filter sublist in realm? How do I create such a list in realm?

Comment: Not without support for the `ALL` predicate, which isn't accessible via Realm-Java's APIs.  The way I'd solve this is by having the `myClass`'s PK and the `mySchool`'s PK as a field of `myStudests` object and then I could query directly against `myStudests`.

Comment: By using that I won't be able to get a list if Schools. and even if I fetch the school form the primary key. The school object will have all the class and students irrespective of the ispresent value